# Cast collection from IGrouping to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a very large collection consistings in my millions of elements. I need to keep everything as IEnumerable otherwise I get an OutOfMemoryException.
My problem is that I have to do some grouping like that :

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> mycollection = dao.RetrieveBigCollection-();
var mycollection = mycollection.GroupBy(x => x.Date1);
```

And later in the program, the collection will be fetched by some library which uses reflection. The problem is that after grouping the collection is of type IGrouping, and this library expects a `IEnumerable<MyClass>`. I need to convert it back to a `IEnumerable<MyClass>`, and my constraint is that I cannot call ToList() otherwise I get an OutOfMemoryException.

Any idea ?

Comment: `IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement>`, so what's the problem exactly?

Comment: `IGrouping<TKey, TValue>` already implements `IEnumerable<TValue>`.  You don't have a problem.

Comment: I agree that it implements IEnumerable but the problem is that the collection is not seen as a IEnumerable<MyClass> when I use reflection on it. Someone would like to cast it so that it seen as a IEnumerable<MyClass> with Reflection. This is usually the case when I call .ToList after grouping but I can't do it in that situation

Comment: @red2nb: Then you're using Reflection wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it to see if there's something to improve. I compare the type of  mycollection.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]  with the type of MyClass. But there's probably something I can do better here.

Comment: Instead of converting, try casting?

Comment: You need to look at the implemented interfaces and find `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @SLaks you were write, I have been able to enumerable the collection without problem. I was throwing an exception whenever the collection wasn't exactly of type IEnumerable<T> but it made no sense since the important thing is that the collection can be iterated over.

Comment: I don't know if my question will help someone else, since I was looking in the wrong direction. I think I will remove it

Answer (score 4):

`GroupBy` returns `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`, which you could *flatten* as:

```
groupings.SelectMany(x => x);
```

However, you will still run into memory issues, because groupings internally keep a collection in memory, so your whole enumerable will be pulled into memory anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is a lot late, but for others that may come looking, you should be able to use `Select`:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> mycollection = dao.RetrieveBigCollection-();
var mycollection = mycollection.GroupBy(x => x.Date1)
                               .Select(xg => xg.Select(x => x));
```

The result will be an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<MyClass>>`.